How to make undo and redo feature?
I hope you're well.
I'm design a software like notepad or simple text editor. I want to make an undo an redo feature and i don't know witch algorithm i can use to made it.
Any help ? I'm using flutter and dart for coding

You forgot to post your attempt to solve this problem.

there are two major approaches I know of: storing the entire state into a history list on every change, and storing just the changes ("diffs"/"delta"), or some combination of the two (e.g. based on the size of the change or document, either store the state or the diff)

Try to give replay bloc a shot -> https://pub.dev/packages/replay_bloc. Looks like it has undo and redo support built into it.
